# How to change the role associated with Airflow user?

Tags: airflow

I am setting up users in Airflow installation using -

```
airflow create_user -r Viewer -u wsmith -f Will -l Smith -p xxxx -e xxxxx@gmail.com
```

Now if I want to change the role from `Viewer` to `Admin`- how would do I do that ?

Is my only option to do it via the UI ? Could I update the database tables directly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via backend database tables.

Within the airflow schema:

```
select * from AB_ROLE;
```

--- This will list all the available roles that you have

```
update AB_USER_ROLE 
set ROLE_ID = <desired role from above>
where 
USER_ID in (select ID from AB_USER where USERNAME = <USERID>);
```

--- Update to desired role.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the user and create back with new role and same credentials

```
airflow delete_user 
airflow create_user  -r <new_role> -u <old_username> -p <password>  -f Firstname -l Lastname -e email@domain.com
```